# How to construct class instance with super?

Tags: python, constructor

I am looking at this example right now

```
class TravellingSalesmanProblem(Annealer):

    """Test annealer with a travelling salesman problem.
    """

    # pass extra data (the distance matrix) into the constructor
    def __init__(self, state, distance_matrix):
        self.distance_matrix = distance_matrix
        super(TravellingSalesmanProblem, self).__init__(state)  # important!
```

Cloned from [simanneal](https://github.com/perrygeo/simanneal)

If I decide to change the constructor

```
def __init__(self, state, distance_matrix):
    self.state = state
    super(TravellingSalesmanProblem, self).__init__(distant_matrix)
```

This is how class Anealer looks like

```
class Annealer(object):
       __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    # defaults
    Tmax = 25000.0
    Tmin = 2.5
    steps = 50000
    updates = 100
    copy_strategy = 'deepcopy'
    user_exit = False
    save_state_on_exit = False

    # placeholders
    best_state = None
    best_energy = None
    start = None

    def __init__(self, initial_state=None, load_state=None):
        if initial_state is not None:
            self.state = self.copy_state(initial_state)
        elif load_state:
            self.load_state(load_state)
        else:
            raise ValueError('No valid values supplied for neither \
            initial_state nor load_state')

        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.set_user_exit)
```

It has bunch of other methods too,but that would take too much space.

How would the new TravellingSalesmanProblem instance differ with the previous one?

Comment: Does `Annealer.__init__` expect a state or a distance matrix as its argument…? That's a rather important difference, is it not?

Comment: I will edit now.

Comment: @ThomasWeller My simulated annealing problem is much more complicated,the example is traveling salesman.

Comment: Well, `Annealer.__init__` wants a state. It doesn't expect to be passed a distance matrix. So don't pass it one in the call to `super`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would the new TravellingSalesmanProblem instance differ with the previous one?

In step 1, you would assign the state

```
self.state = state
```

In step 2 you would pass the distant matrix as a parameter to the init method

```
super(TravellingSalesmanProblem, self).__init__(distant_matrix)
```

That init method take the first parameter and interpret it as `initial_state`.

```
self.state = self.copy_state(initial_state)
```

That means: the original state is lost and the distant matrix becomes your state.

Conclusion: It's a mess.